# Displaying audio and video content on android

Tags: android, multimedia

For a project in work, we are getting a multimedia company to make 7 x 3 minutes film = around 21 minutes of video. ( with H.264/1280x720/1000kbps = about 200 Mb) which will then be stored on a MicroSD on the Samsung Galaxy S. These video files will be called by an app that I am developing. 
They will also record all the text in audio (voice-over) as a separate file = about 60 minutes audio (with mp3 size about 60 Mb)
Total media around 260 Mb. They will be working on a Apple computer.

I know very little about multimedia - even though I apparantly have a masters in it - and was wondering if someone could help me answer some of these questions?

What would be the max suitable size for each of the files if stored on a 4GB Micro SD?

What is the minimum quality for display on a Samsung Galaxy S?

What is the best file format for display on the device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What would be the max suitable size for each of the files if stored on a 4GB Micro SD?

   File Size is a function of video bitrate and duration of the clip. Video Bitrate is usually proportional to Video Resolution. For a 21 minute clip, @ 8 Mbps, File Size would be ~ (21 * 60 * 8) /8, i.e.  1.2 GB. This should be okay for you.
2. What is the minimum quality for display on a Samsung Galaxy S?

   Galaxy S I think has WVGA Screen Resolution, however it can decode up to 720P. i.e. You can run a video of resolution 1280x720. If the particulr Galaxy S you are talking about, has HDMI output, then you can go ahead with 720P Content. Otherwise, on phone you wont see the difference between 720P Vs WVGA playback.
3. What is the best file format for display on the device?

   Android comes with H264/MP4 combination. These days bluray content (High definition video) is becoming popular. i.e. 1080P / 720P H264/mkv format. This you can use if the phone supports mkv. Otherwise go with 720P H264 in MP4.

Shash

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no most suitable file size. It depends on the quality of the video and if you'll only need 21 minutes of video, you'll have plenty of storage space.
2. There's no point in doing 720p video on a display that doesn't show more than WVGA resolution. You could easily change the video resolution to WVGA and keep the bitrate. It should look just great.
3. I'd probably go with H.264 for the Galaxy S2.

Good luck!